# A problem on the factorizability of certain a boolean multivariate polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, polynomials, computer-science

Let $N$ be a positive integer and let $[N] := \{1,2,\ldots,N\}$. Given a non-empty collection $K$ of a subsets of $[N]$ and field $\mathbb F$, define a polynomial $f_K$ over $\{-1,+1\}$ in indeterminates $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ by

$$
f_K := \sum_{A \in K}x_A,
$$
where $x_A := \prod_{i \in A} x_i$ and $x_\emptyset := 1$.

**Question.** Under what conditions on $K$ can this polynomial be factorized like so $f_K = \prod_j g_j$, where the $g_j$'s are polynomials each of which has degree $1$ ?

Ideally, I'd like a complete characterization of all such $K$. However, I'm fine with examples, as long as they are sufficiently broad.

### Examples

- **1. Transversal of a partition.** Let $G_1,\ldots,G_k$ form a partition of $[N]$, and let $K$ be the collection of subsets of $[N]$ which contain exactly on element of each $G_j$. Then, since $K$ can be identified with the cartesian product $G_1 \times \ldots \times G_k$, it is easy to see that
  $$
  f_K = \sum_{(i_1,\ldots,i_k) \in G_1 \times \ldots G_k} x_{i_1}\ldots x_{i_k} = \prod_{j=1}^k g_j,\text{ where }g_j := \sum_{i \in G_j} x_i.
  $$
- **2. Subsets of a given size.** Let $n \le N$ be a positive integer and take for $K$ the collection of subsets of $[N]$ with exactly $n$ elements.
  Then, it is clear that
  $$
  f_K = g^n, \text{ where }g := \sum_{i=1}^N x_i.
  $$
- **3. Power set.** Let $K$ the powerset of $[N]$. Then,
  $$
  f_K = \prod_{i \in [N]}g_i,\text{ where }g_i := 1+x_i.
  $$
  This result can be proved by induction on $N$. Indeed, for the case $N=1$, it is clear that $\sum_A x_A = x_\emptyset + x_1 = 1+x_1 = \prod_{i \in [N]}(1+x_i)$. Suppose the result true for $N=n$. We prove it for $N=n+1$. Observe that the powerset $P_{n+1}$ of $[n+1]$ can be partitioned like so: $P_{n+1} = P_n \cup P_n'$, where $P'_n := \{A \cup \{n
  +1\} \mid A \in P_n\}$. Thus,

$$
\begin{split}
f_{P_{n+1}} &= f_{P_n} + f_{P_n'} = \prod_{i \in [n]}(1+x_i) + \prod_{i \in [n]}(1+x_i x_{n+1})\\
& = (1+x_{n+1})\prod_{i \in [n]}(1+x_i) = \prod_{i \in [n+1]}(1+x_i).
\end{split}
$$